# ios - replacing an image with a video player dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

My app (Swift 3, with a `UIStoryboard`) shows a list of episodes from a show. Whenever the user clicks on an episode from the table, he/she gets a detail view which shows (top to bottom):

- the episode's image
- the title
- a description of the episode and technical information

Depending on the user type, instead of showing the episode's image, we would like to have a video player so people who are subscribed can just start watching the video (unsubscribed users would just see the image).

Based on the subscribed status of our users, a video player should be playing the content (subscribed) or showing an image (unsubscribed).

Is there a way to dynamically remove the image and replace it with the video player in the exact same spot and dimensions? And if so, what would happen with the Auto Layout contraints currently applied to the image?

Comment: You should create your own AVPlayerLayer, which is a CALayer instance to which the AVPlayer can direct its visual output. Create UIView in Storyboard with your size, add your UIImageView to it and create outlets for both. In code, initialize the AVPlayerLayer with your AVPlayer and add as subview to the container view. From there you can hide / play etc.

Comment: Thanks, Fabijan. will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a `UIView` on top of the `UIImageView` in storyboard. Align it to all 4 edges of `UIImageView`. And then hide and show them according to requirement by setting `isHidden` property.
Then, Insert the `AVPlayer` in the `UIView` through code.

Answer (score 2):

### Steps

The following solution works for both `UIStoryboard` and UI in code.

1. In InterfaceBuilder drag a `UIView` of preferred size onto the canvas, add your auto layout constraints and create an outlet (called "containerView")
2. Configure an AVPlayer with a `URL` or file, initialize an AVPlayerLayer instance with the player and add the layer to the `containerView's` layer hierarchy
3. Add an `UIImageView` on top of the container view
4. Based on your condition, show / hide / stop / play your movie and image

### Quick code example

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    private var imageView: UIImageView!
    private var isUserSubscribed = true


    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Video
        let url = URL(string: "https://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8")!
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = containerView.bounds
        containerView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        // Image
        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "someImage"))
        imageView.frame = containerView.frame
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)

        // Condition
        if isUserSubscribed {
            imageView.isHidden = true
            avPlayer.play()
        } else {
            imageView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

[image: Screenshot]

### Further options

With this approach you need to add your own playback controls, which basically boils down to adding buttons with actions, triggering `AVPlayer.play()`, `AVPlayer.stop()` etc.

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps you mentioned but I'm having an issue with the image. I placed the UIView in storyboard with constraints for top, right, left and aspect ratio. I then created the UIImageView programatically, setting the imageView frame to the containerView frame and added it as a subview to the container view. The problem is that a big gap appears between the top of the UIView and the top of the UIImageView.